# what is the format of the data which circulate between the layers of a n-tier architecture

Tags: n-tier-architecture, 3-tier

I was wondering about the way the data are transferred between the layers of a n-tier architecture ? For example, in spring web mvc, under which format do they move from one layer to another ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a n-tier architecture, the format of the data is generally defined by the tier.  If you are communicating between a database tier and a business logic tier, it will probably be JDBC.  If it is between a business-logic tier and a web tier it will probably be either a service protocol (JSON, SOAP, etc), or a remoting protocol (RMI, etc).  If it is between the client (web browser) and the web tier, it's probably HTML or JSON.